# how to see that isometries are distance preserving

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

A riemannian metric induces a distance function that makes the riemannian manifold a metric space. Intuitively, it certainly should be true that every isometry is distance-preserving. But how to actually see this? Via pull-back of the metric, the speed of the (piece-wise) curve can be transformed under an isometry, but how to see that the infimum of lengths of transformed curves is the same as the original? Thanks!

Comment: You also map every (sufficiently smooth) curve across (and back), so the infimum of lengths is the same.